# java.lang.IllegalStateException Fragment not attached to Activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

After I receive a response with Volley, I have to get back to the main fragment.
I have two different volley requests , depending on some condition, I'll call it 'a' in this example.
The weird thing is the when **a==1, popBackStack gets me successfully** to the main fragment .
**When a==0 it crashes** and I receive  `java.lang.IllegalStateException Fragment not attached to Activity`
I tried creating a new main fragment (transaction.commit....) but it didn't help.

```
if( a == 0 )
{
    VolleyManager.add(jsnObj,
        new RequestListener() {

                    @Override
                    public <T> void onSuccess(T object) {
                        mFragmentManager.popBackStack(DataManager.BACK_STACK_KEY_MAIN_FRAGMENT, 0);
                    }
                    });
                }
else if( a==1 )
{
    VolleyManager.update(jsnObj,
        new RequestListener() {

                @Override
                public <T> void onSuccess(T object) {
                        mFragmentManager.popBackStack(DataManager.BACK_STACK_KEY_MAIN_FRAGMENT, 0);
                }   
                });
    }
```

Error -

```
  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment MainFragment{6aaaf7f} not attached to Activity
  at android.app.Fragment.getResources(Fragment.java
```

The problem seems to be with the `getResources()`, but I do the same thing when a==1 and I've got no problems at all.

Comment: Can you post whole error log.

Comment: I see the crash inside `MainFragment`, can you also update its code.

Comment: I updated it. thanks

Comment: Did u try to implement onErrorResponse()?

Comment: yes.. but the response I get is successful , and I can see in debug that it in fact gets into the onSuccess callback method.

Comment: @BVtp, just check my answer and see if it works.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like that by the time `AsyncTask` finishes and calls `onPostExecute`, the `MainFragment` has been detached from its `activity`. So either the `activity` has already been destroyed or `fragment` was never attached.

So if fragment is **not** attached to the `activity`, it can't access resources because that requires `context` and fragment doesn't have but `activity` does.

So you should check if `activity` is `null` or not before calling `getResources`.

Update the code like this:

```
if(getActivity()!=null){
    String streetFormat = getActivity().getResources().getString( R.string.address_name_string );
    ....
}
```

Comment: It doesnt work.. It doesn't crash but it doesn't get back to the MainFragment. I just see a blank page.

Comment: Then you are not loading the fragment. add code of how are you adding the `MainFragment`

Answer (score 3):

You have to cancel your requests on

> onDestroyView()

method of the fragment or check if the fragment is already alive and added to host activity or not
I'd go with something like this:

```
onDestroyView(){ Volley.cancelAllRequests() }
```

or

```
onResponse(){ if(getActivity() != null && isAdded(){ // here handle the response and update views, otherwise just cache the response!}}
```

Comment: You cannot suggest onDestroyView for interrupt http calls. We must destroy all request when onStop callback called by system.

Comment: @nurisezgin Then what happens when a pending request gets canceled in the onStop and then the user presses back to it? Sees a uninitialized page and no request is being processed!

Comment: That's a google document for cancellation of volley requests. fyi https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html#cancel

Answer (score 0):

`getResources()` must be called from something that has `Context`, like the activity. The fragment itself does not have the `Context` since it does not implement it. If you're using `getResources()` in a fragment, you can try this:

```
String streetFormat = getActivity().getResources().getString( R.string.address_name_string );
```

Comment: It doesnt work.. It doesn't crash but it doesn't get back to the MainFragment. I just see a blank page.

Comment: Well, that just means that some other logic of yours is not good. We've fixed the crashing caused by `getResources()`